# How to find all possible polynomials over a given finite field?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

How would I find the possible polynomials over GF(p)? I'm trying to figure out which polynomials of a specific given finite field have no roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a specific example, say $\mathbb{Z}_3$. The degree zero polynomials are: $$0,1,2,$$ the degree 1 are: $$x, x+1,x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2,$$ the degree 2 are: $$x^2, x^2+1, x^2+2, x^2+x, x^2+x+1, x^2+x+2,...$$

See the pattern? This generalizes upwards. For $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, the order is infinite, unless you discuss only polynomials of degree $\le n$, in which case some elementary combinatorics gives you $p^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Makes sense!

Comment: Hi @walkar how about such polynomials like x - 1, x - 2? Are they being counted in p^(n + 1)?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $x-1=x+(-1) = x+2$ since $2+1=0$.